# python list from truncated data

Tags: python

I have a text file which contains  data of the form:

```
decimal=12668098908\
75899080808908098
decimal=2987979878\    
757675765786686
... etc
```

I want to make a vector A[i] where for each *i*, I shall get the *i*-th integer (without the \) from the previous data.

edit : For instance

```
A[0]=1266809890875899080808908098, 
A[1]=2987979878757675765786686, etc
```

Comment: Just a couple of Python conventions: "vector" in C++ is (roughly) a "list" in Python. And variables are usually lowercase_with_underscores.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the dataset is sufficiently large that we can't just slice the string up in memory, perhaps the best way to do this would be to create a generator.

```
def nums(file_handle):
    # read the first line in as our initial string
    linestr = file_handle.readline()[8:].strip('\\\n')

    # loop over the remaining lines in the file handle
    for line in file_handle:
        if line.startswith('decimal='):
            # first yield our existing string
            yield linestr

            # then begin a new one
            linestr = line[8:].strip('\\\n')

        # otherwise,
        else:
            linestr += line.strip('\\\n')

    # yield fianal string
    yield linestr

f = open(<filename>, 'r')
A = list(nums(f))
```

If the dataset isn't large we can do this with a quick string replace and a regex:

```
f = open(<filename>, 'r')
A = re.findall('decimal=(\d+)', f.read().replace('\\\n', ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

A class-y approach that's open to things like lazy reading (for big file and few reads):

```
class DataFileList(object):

    def __init__(self, file_path):
        with open(file_path) as f:
            self.lines = f.readlines()

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        line_number = index * 2
        return int('{}{}'.format(
            self.lines[line_number].split('=')[1].strip('\n\\ \t'),
            self.lines[line_number + 1].strip('\n \t'),
        ))
```

Usage:

```
a = DataFileList('my_file.txt')
print(a[0])  # 1111111190875899080808908098
```